# Formatting text in modal popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog, popup

I've written a function which takes formatted text on a page (line breaks and paragraphs rather than styling) and displays it in a modal popup but it's in a continuous string and doesn't include the formatting/line breaks. Below is my latest failed attempt and I've also tried .html() and innerHTML(). There's always a way but what is it? :-)

```
$('body').on('click', '#aPoppingOutForSomeText', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    ShowAdvicePopup();
});

function ShowAdvicePopup() {
    var $divInner = $('<div><table class="fullWidth"><tr><td><span>' + $('#txtCOMMENTS').text() + '</span></td></tr></table></div>');
    var $divOuter = $('<div></div>').append($divInner);    
    
    $divOuter.dialog({
        title: 'MDT Comments',
        modal: true,
        width: 900,
        open: function (event, ui) { },
        close: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you show what is the text and how it is displayed in popup?

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma it's just random text copied off the internet into a <textarea></textarea> control and it has line breaks

Comment: The element you insert into needs to have css `white-space:pre` (or `pre-wrap`) - you could also(instead?) use the `<pre></pre>` tag instead of `<span>`

Comment: @freedomn-m this did the trick thank you $('<div><table class="fullWidth"><tr><td><pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-family: Arial;">' + $('#txtCOMMENTS').text() + '</pre></td></tr></table></div>')

Comment: @freedomn-m next question how do you treat potentially malicious mark up in text as just text - so for instance <b></b> shouldn't make text bold but should just appear as <b></b>?

Comment: Use jquery instead of building HTML as a string.  Remove the +txtcomment+ part then `$("pre").text($("#txtcomment").val())` after you append to the DOM.   (you have .text()?  should be .val() if it's a textarea, maybe doesn't matter for textarea).

Comment: @freedomn-m aha - i did this and it's now performing as required - thank you for helping with the bonus question! :-) $divInner.append($('<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-family: Arial;"></pre>').text($('#txtCOMMENTS').val()));